# Full Calendar print background color?

Tags: css, printing, calendar, fullcalendar, styles

I am using the Fullcalendar plugin and am trying to print the week calendar but wanting to show the background color of my events, At most it prints with the specified border color but background color doesnt print, I have specified on chrome to print color/images and have added the css

**-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;**

here is my code snippet for two events with different color, is there a workaround to accomplishing this?:

```
   <a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" style="background-color: rgb(71, 208, 65); border-color: rgb(71, 208, 65); z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%; margin-right: 20px; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; top: 84px; bottom: -378px;">
    <div class="fc-content">
        <div class="fc-time" data-start="10:00" data-full="10:00 AM - 5:00 PM">
            <span>10:00 - 5:00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="fc-title">breakfast 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fc-bg"> </div>
</a>
<a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" style="background-color: rgb(0, 188, 242); border-color: rgb(0, 188, 242); z-index: 2; left: 50%; right: 0%; top: 210px; bottom: -294px;">
    <div class="fc-content">
        <div class="fc-time" data-start="1:00" data-full="1:00 PM - 3:00 PM">
            <span>1:00 - 3:00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="fc-title">breakfast</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fc-bg">
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Did you check the `Background graphics` option ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yes i did

Comment: Do the colors show up in the preview ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak they do not, only the border color does

Comment: fullCalendar has some print-specific CSS rules. You'd need to change or override those rules